# Windows NDIS filter - how to check if port is used by operating system

Tags: windows, tcp, kernel, ndis, windows-kernel

I am writing a windows NDIS filter driver and would like to be able to query from inside the kernel about the status of a tcp port (is it in use?).
When the driver is in IRQL = dispatch_level, can I use WSK Network API or anything else to query if a port is being used by the operating system?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no visible (read: documented) method for doing that. One option is to use GetTcpTable2, parse and send the information to the driver using an IOCTL. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6499898/397604) for an example how to do it from the usermode, you'll have to add some work to process and send it down to the driver.

It is also possible to go through the less preferable way of reverse engineering the API used by GetTcpTable2 and use it yourself. See the discussion in [OSR](http://osronline.com/showThread.CFM?link=167887), including a few leads and a few good reasons why not to do it.