# Check for ports that are in use

Tags: c, winsock, port-scanning

Is there an Windows API that can determine which given ports are closed/in-use on a certain IP address (localhost for my scenario)?

I have tried the following:

```
SOCKADDR_IN saddr;
saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);

WSADATA WSA = {0};
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WSA) == 0) {
    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (s != SOCKET_ERROR) {
        saddr.sin_port = htons(Port); // `Port` evaluates to any given number 1 - 65535
        if (bind(s, (SOCKADDR *) &saddr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            if (GetLastError() != 0) {
                DWORD a = GetLastError(); // WSAGetLastError() points to this anyways, so whatever
                a = 0; // breakpoint here
            }
        }
    }
} 
closesocket(s);
```

And even when I check ports that are already in use by a given process, like `MYSQL (3306)` used by XAMPP in my scenario. It still doesn't return `SOCKET_ERROR` for `bind`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: GetTcpTable2() enumerates open TCP ports.  Pretty unlikely you should be doing that, how would the machine on the other end of the wire know what port you ended up selecting?

Comment: @HansPassant INADDR_LOOPBACK in the `s_addr` member refers to localhost. I'm trying to scan ports of the host machine, not another machine.  Also, the reason I wasn't using `GetTcpTable2()` is because its only supported from Vista and onwards, and I need to do it natively so XP is supported too.

Answer (score 1):

A bind() call does not necessarily fail even when another socket got bound to the interface: It may be possible that the socket did not got bound with the [SO_EXCLUSIVEADDR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/cc150667(v=vs.85).aspx%20/%20SO_EXCLUSIVEADDR) option. When binding to a specific interface (such as loopback/127.0.0.1 on a certain port) which got bound by another socket before, you basically hijack the interface and from there on receive all the packets heading to it. See this table from the provided MSDN link for a detailed map of the behaviour (Specific2 only applies if the first bind() was to a specific interface):

[image: Specific2 only applies if the first bind() was to a specific interface]

In order to determine which applications are bound to which interface, you may have a look at [Finding tcp ports used by application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499845/finding-tcp-ports-used-by-application).

Comment: This information was useful (for that I up-voted you), however I was able to figure out another approach to my problem by using `NtDeviceIoControlFile` with the `IOCTL_TDI_QUERY_INFORMATION` to query the `Tcp/Udp` device objects for all current running processes on the system `NtQuerySystemInformation` enumeration.